# Assembly loops loop too many times

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, fasm

I am very new to assembly (Started learning yesterday) and have a problem with loops:

The code below *should* print the values 0-49, but instead it prints 0-49 and then ~20 lines of rubbish (I'm assuming this is part of the stack that other programs/other bits of the program are using). I expect the problem is the second loop, `.loop`, as it's printing the wrong number of lines, and printing is handled by `.loop`.

I am using the FASM (Flat Assembler) program to compile this.

**Code:**

```
format PE console
include "win32ax.inc"
start:
    mov ecx, 50 ;number of loops
    .mainloop: ;for testing purposes, just pushes 49-0 onto the stack
        push ecx ;push onto stack
        dec ecx ;decrement counter
        jnz .mainloop ;jump if counter not zero

    mov ecx, 50 ;reset ecx (counter)
    .loop: ;prints the stack, should print 0-49 but also prints garbage at the end
        pop eax ;pop from stack to eax
        cinvoke printf,formatstring,eax ;print eax
        dec ecx ;decrement counter
        jnz .loop ;loop if counter not zero
    int 15;wait 5 seconds ish
    invoke ExitProcess ;exit

formatstring    db "%d",13,10,0 ;to print digits instead of ASCII chars

section '.idata' import data readable ;stuff I copied but seems to work
    library msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll',\ ;don't understand it
        kernel32,'kernel32.dll'   ;^
    import  msvcrt,printf,'printf';^^
    import  kernel32,ExitProcess,"ExitProcess";^^^
```

Thanks in advance.

*p.s. How do I format the code with syntax highlighting?*

Comment: Probably `cinvoke printf,formatstring,eax ;print eax` does change the `ECX` register, because it is considered volatile by the OS.

Comment: I'll look into it

Comment: Yep, your right. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ecx` is one of the "caller-saved" registers, meaning any function call can modify `ecx` and it is the caller's job to save/restore it where necessary.

[See also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Register_preservation):

> According to the Intel ABI to which the vast majority of compilers conform, the EAX, EDX, and ECX are to be free for use within a procedure or function, and need not be preserved.

Your call to `printf` in the loop likely clobbers `ecx`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `cinvoke printf,formatstring,eax` changes the `ECX` register, as pointed out by zx485. It turns out it also changes the `EDX` register.

To fix it, I changed to using the `EBX` register, which is *not* modified by `cinvoke printf,formatstring,eax`.

I hope this helps someone.

EDIT: melpomene posted a much better answer.